# Swift compiler error from writing a for loop within a closure

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have a class, `GGAdvertiser`

```
class GGAdvertiser: GGObject {
    var id:NSInteger?
    var name:NSString?

    func getAdvertisers(success:AnyObject! -> Void, failure:NSError! -> Void) {
        GGNetworking.shared.request("advertisers", params: nil, methodType: GGHTTPType.get, success:({ response in
            var advertisers = NSMutableArray(capacity: response.count)
            let array:NSArray! = response as NSArray

            for dict:NSDictionary! in array {
                let advertiser = GGAdvertiser(dictionary:dict)
                assert(advertiser == nil, "Advertiser must serialize; can't be nil'")
                advertisers.addObject(advertiser)
            }
            success(advertisers)
            }), failure:({ error in
                GGNetworking.defaultError(error)
                failure(error)
        }))
    }
}
```

Curiously, the very second I write the `for dict:NSDictionary! in array` in Xcode, it starts throwing that "SourceKitService Terminated" error message.

I've tried every possible way to implement that for loop into the function but I get the same result each time. This issue is near impossible to diagnose because that error turns off the compiler's error reporting. In other words, I'm not given a message as to what the problem is.

I would normally just keep going since it doesn't result in an error, but it flashes the same error message every 5 seconds or so (as if to retry running SourceKit). Plus, I don't have code formatting or autocompletion. All are very annoying...

Any insight into the issue would be great

Comment: [File a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really weird issue I run into often in Xcode 6 beta. You should, of course, [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) about it.

As for getting around it, I find that the only way to make it work is to do this:

```
for dict:AnyObject! in array { //Play with whether to have a ! or not. I can't remember which works.
    let advertiser = GGAdvertiser(dictionary:(dict as NSDictionary!))
    assert(advertiser == nil, "Advertiser must serialize; can't be nil'")
    advertisers.addObject(advertiser)
}
```

For some reason it freaks out when the object inside the forin loop is said to be anything except AnyObject. So I just say that it's an AnyObject, then cast it to whatever I know it to be when I need to use it. My best guess is that the typechecker is freaking out.

It's a terrible hack, but it's better than trying to code without our beloved formatting & completion.

Comment: Sadly, this still causes the same compiler bug... no matter what variation I try.

Answer (score 0):

```
let array:NSArray! = response as NSArray

for dict:NSDictionary! in array {
    let advertiser = GGAdvertiser(dictionary:dict)
    assert(advertiser == nil, "Advertiser must serialize; can't be nil'")
    advertisers.addObject(advertiser)
}
```

I feel like the problem here is that `array` could be `nil` in your fast enumeration (*for dict: NSDictionary! in array*), and that the case should be handled before that.

If you **know** that it won't be nil, that you could rewrite it as:

```
for dict: NSDictionary! in array! { ...
```

If there's some chance that it *might* be nil, then I would use 'optional binding' and wrap the enumeration in a test:

```
if let responseArray = array {
    for dict: NSDictionary! in responseArray {
    ...
```

Comment: You're right, but I tried this implementation and it was giving me the same error. I believe you would have normally had a point, but it's a compiler bug :/

Comment: really? it works for me... maybe comment out the line before making the changes  :)  and then uncomment when it's in the right form

Comment: I was trying this before I asked the question and I tried it again just now to no avail. I know that you're right however (or at least, I agree with you).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that NSArray maps to Array, so the line:

```
for dict:NSDictionary! in array {
```

can't be properly mapped.  Move the conversion to the array and you should be ok:

```
for dict in array as Array<NSDictionary> {
```

This will work as long as all array (ever) contains is NSDictionary.  If there's a chance that it doesn't, then you have to use a solution similar to that suggested by @undo:

```
for item in array {
    if let dict = item as? NSDictionary {
```

Note that in neither case does dict need to be unwrapped, since you know that an NSArray can never contain nil.

Comment: This isn't correct because the object `array` is a non-generic type (`NSArray`) so it would throw an actual compiler error. In this case, this appears to be a compiler bug

Answer (score 0):

So I filed a bug report. I'll update this answer w/ a link when I figure out how to share it.

The workaround that FINALLY worked for me was like so:

```
for dict:AnyObject in response as NSArrary {
```

Literally any other variation I tried didn't work. I have no idea why this works over any of the other solutions, but it does, so alas...